# Web server opens old index file in a strange way

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, web-server, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

PC: Old desktop PC,
OS: Ubuntu LTS (latest),
Web Server: Using Apache (latest),
FTP: Gadmin PROFTPD,
DNS: Using NOIP,
Also using the NOIP dynamic update client,

in my var/www/html I kept an index/html that was very basic as I am just learning html/scc. I decided to access this using FTP and update it to my newer nicer website. I did this and put on the new index.html and style.css. I open it on any other computer and no problem it opens as it should.

However if I type in my DNS on my server it references the old index.html which I don't even know where it is! If I put in my public IP address from my server however it will go to the new website and NOIP has been updated by myself to ensure it has the latest public IP address.

I even did a file search for index.html and looked in all of them and can't find the old index.html anywhere. Lastly I restarted it with no luck.

Why is it that only on the server using the DNS it will reference the old index.html? But every other way I try reference the server it comes up with the new website?

update:
I found that on my sever if I simple add /index.html it will go to the correct website. Without that it will then go to the old index.html (wherever it is).

Comment: you are encouraged to answer you own question if you find the answer.

Comment: Most likely a caching issue.